# Parameter not being passed in MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, url-routing

I have route defined in routehandler.cs file. In controller when I put debugger on Request method. I get countrycode value as en or fr. But in path1 instead of products or produits I get {productSource} as value in parameter.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductMatrix",
    "{countryCode}/{productSource}/{productId}/{selectedProductId}",
    new { controller = "Master", action = "Request", path1 = "{productSource}", selectedProductId = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new
    {
        countryCode = "en|fr",
        productString = "products|produits"
    });
```

Comment: `path1 = "{productSource}"` makes no sense (your route does not contain a segment for `path1`). Niether does `productString = "products|produits"`. What are you expecting this to do, and what is the signature of the method(s) you expect this to hit?

Comment: path1 can be any of the two values in productstring and i want that value in controller. Below is the method signature                                                                   
public ActionResult PreRequest(string countryCode, string selectedProductId, string path1)
{

}

Comment: Your route does not contain a segment for `path1` - its impossible to understand what your trying to do here - but best guess is that you mean `"{countryCode}/{path1}/{productId}/{selectedProductId}",` although I have no idea where `{productId}` fits into this, and since the default action is `Request` it would never hit that method anyway.

Comment: And you have no segment for `productstring` so `productString = "products|produits"` makes no sense. And your method does not contain a parameter for `productstring` either